# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'firefox' executable needs to be in PATH with GeckoDriver Firefox Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am trying to open Firefox with selenium,i tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
```

But i got the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'firefox' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

[Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

I tried

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/bin/firefox')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
```

Also tried

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
caps['marionette'] = True
caps['binary'] = '/usr/bin/firefox'
d = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps)
```

`but still did not work.

However, when i tried using the above code replacing the last line with

`d=webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps,executable_path='/usr/bin/firefox')` and having my Firefox closed from background it would open Firefox but I can't simply `d.get("https://www.google.com")` *it gets stuck on Linux homepage* and doesn't open anything.

After typing `whereis firefox` in terminal i got `/usr/bin/firefox`,also if it matters i use python 2.7

**Note**: I hope this isn't a duplicate of the above link because i tried the answers and it didn't fix it.

I installed *geckodriver* from [github](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), and tried `browser=webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")` ,I have placed the driver is the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still not clear why you are seeing the error as:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'firefox' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

In majority of the cases the common PATH related error is associated with **geckodriver**.

However, while working with Selenium 3.x you need to download the latest *GeckoDriver* from [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and save it anywhere in your system and provide the absolute path of the *GeckoDriver* through the argument **`executable_path`**.

The following code block works perfecto to open *Firefox Nightly Browser* (installed at customized location):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.binary_location = '/path/to/firefox'
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path='/path/to/geckodriver')
  driver.get('http://google.com/')
  print("Page title is: %s" %(driver.title))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Page title is: Google
  ```

Comment: it is clear he is using unix your`options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Nightly\firefox.exe'` will not work ,it is clear in the question `whereis firefox` `/usr/bin/firefox`

Comment: @timmy Updated, let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @timmy when the answer got updated, it fixed my problem.